# How will this variable respond

Tags: vba, variables, excel

I'm using Excel VBA but I think this is quite a generic question.

I have the following declaration

`Public newReport As Excel.Workbook`

Later in the code, after I've opened and named an xlsx file `MyBook.xlsx` I point this variable at the file:

`Set newReport = Excel.Workbooks("MyBook.xlsx")`

I'm getting slightly confused again re. variable behaviour.
If I later have MyBook.xlsx open and I execute `ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs` and give it a *new name* say MyBookNew.xlsx will the variable `newReport` be pointed at the new workbook?

Example of related code is the following:

```
Public newReport As Excel.Workbook

Sub FileExperiment()

Set newReport = Excel.Workbooks.Add
newReport.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\MyBook.xlsx"

Set newReport = Excel.Workbooks("MyBook.xlsx")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\MyNewBook.xlsx"

newReport.Close False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`newReport` will be unchanged.

Cut from the help file, regarding the command `SaveCopyAs`:

*Saves a copy of the workbook to a file but doesn't modify the open workbook in memory.*

Comment: so effectively I'm just changing the `Name` property of the file that is in the memory?

Comment: @whytheq No, you just save a copy of the file. Both the `Workbooks` collection and the `newReport` reference are unchanged.

Comment: cool - I see now: it doesn't open the copy it makes just saves a copy so the active book is still MyBook.xlsx which is newReport. Thanks